# How to listen for a keyboard event in dart programming

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm new to google dart and been trying to learn it for a day now.  I'm pretty novice to programming in general and I'm trying to read the documentation; however, I feel a bit overwhelmed.

I would like to know the most proper method of creating a interaction for spacebar [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/KeyCode.html#SPACE) key.  When one would push spacebar, it would toggle between function void startwatch() , void resetwatch()

I believe this is the correct documentation page also [documentation for keyboardEventController](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/KeyboardEventController.html)

```dart
void main() {

}

void startwatch() {
  mywatch.start();
  var oneSecond = new Duration(milliseconds:1);
  var timer = new Timer.repeating(oneSecond, updateTime);
}

void resetwatch() {
  mywatch.reset();
  counter = '00:00:00';
}
```

Any further information needed I'll try to respond immediately.  Thnk you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To listen to keyboard events and toggle between `startwatch()` and `resetwatch()`:

```dart
void main() {
  var started = false;

  window.onKeyUp.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
    print('pressed a key');

    if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.SPACE) {
      print('pressed space');

      if (started) {
        resetwatch();
      } else {
        startwatch();
      }

      started = !started; // A quick way to switch between true and false.
    }
  });
}
```

`window` is an instance of [`Window`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Window.html) class. It's automatically provided for you.

There's also a handy class called [`KeyEvent`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/KeyEvent.html), which attempts to eliminate cross-browser inconsistencies. These inconsistencies are usually related to special keys.

Comment: The docs on `KeyEvent` tell us to add events to a `Stream`, but streams don't support adding events, it would have to be a `Sink` or `StreamController`. So how do we proceed? I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421740/4756173) to this one.