# How to Simulate a Keyboard Event in Dart HTML

Tags: html, dart, tdd

## 1. Problem and Context

I'm trying to create a browser extension with Dart, more specifically, one that deals with adding keyboard shortcuts to certain websites.

To guarantee better TDD, I'm trying to simulate keyboard events during the tests. However, it seems like many things have changed when it comes to Dart's HTML APIs and I haven't been able to figure out how to make them work.

## 2. What I'm Trying

I would like to register a specific keystroke — so the generic [`KeyboardEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/KeyboardEvent-class.html) won't cut it apparently, only the [`KeyEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/KeyEvent-class.html) class can handle that. So far, I'm trying something like this:

```dart
document.body.dispatchEvent(KeyEvent('keypress', keyCode: 65, charCode: 97));
```

From which I receive an error close to this:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.
```

I've also tried the code above with `document`, `document.window` and `window`, none worked. Something similar can be found in the [`KeyEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/KeyEvent-class.html) documentation. However, they mention `add`ing to a `Stream`, which I don't think is possible. It would have to be a `Sink` instead.

If I'm not able to solve this via dispatching events, I think I'll have to simply inject mocks into the tests.

## 3. More Resources

2 outdated answers which have helped me so far were:

1. [dart how to create, listen, and emits custom event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15726189/4756173)
2. [How do I listen for custom events in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902121/4756173)

Comment: For simple testing purposes, using `KeyboardEvent` seems fine, but you won't be able to use the `key` property, only simpler ones like `location`.

Comment: I've posted about this on the [source repo](https://github.com/dart-lang/html/issues/125).